# How to find a file without showing "/"

Tags: filenames

im a beginner and I have no idea about the syntaxe of script shell Linux.

I have to show only files ending with (.sh) which is already done.

but these file ending with (.sh) their names has to be without ".sh" and "./" shown, when I used cut

I took everything between the two points

Exemple : ./hello.sh

output : /hello

so the slash is still there and I didn't find any solution about it
[image: EXEMPLE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using find/cut like that will break any files in sub dirs. In the current dir, try `ls | cut -d"." -f1`, or if there are sub dirs, try `find * -name "*.sh" | sed "s/.sh$//"`

With the new find, the `*` gets expanded to all the entries in the current directory, so it could be (for example `find file1.sh dir1 dir2 -name "*.sh"`. The pipe through sed, just strips the end off.

Comment: it worked thank you so much ! but could you explain to me what   was exactly wrong please ? i don't wanna just copy the solution

Comment: It's find's the search path. You set it to `.`. With the new find, the `*` gets expanded to all the entries in the current directory, so it could be (for example `find file1.sh dir1 dir2 -name "*.sh"`. The pipe through `sed`, just strips the end off. Hope that explains it.

Comment: If you want to "improve" on it, try tests for whether they are files or directories, and check for execution permissions.

Comment: okay I understood, thank you so much, last thing, how to make them in descending order ?

Comment: I searched for it everything and i couldn't find the syntaxe or the function to do that for file names

Comment: Add ` | sort -r` to the end.

Comment: sort r- doesn't work

Comment: Not sure if that's just a typo here, or in your terminal, but it should be "sort -r", not "sort r-"

Comment: yea I miss typed it i wrote it -r in terminal

Comment: nvm it works now, i miss typed it in terminal

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to show the names matching the pattern `*.sh` from the current directory, without the `.sh` suffix:

```bsh
for name in ./*.sh; do
    basename "$name" .sh
done
```

The `basename` utility outputs the filename portion of the pathname given as the first argument, and if a second argument is given, that string is stripped off from the end of the name.  The above loop does not consider *hidden* names.

If you need to do this recursively, then you may use `find` like so:

```bsh
find . -name '*.sh' -exec basename {} .sh \;
```

This calls `basename` on each found pathnames and strips off the `sh` filename suffix from each.

If you're using the `bash` shell, you may also do this like so:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
shopt -s globstar

for name in ./**/*.sh; do
    basename "$name" .sh
done
```

This sets a few shell options to be able to find hidden names (`dotglob`), to avoid looping at all if there are *no* matches (`nullglob`), and to be able to use the `**` globbing pattern (`globstar`; matches "recursively").

With the `zsh` shell, you would get a similar effect with

```bsh
print -rC1 -- ./**/*.sh(DN:r:t)
```

... where the `D` and `N` in the *globbing qualifier* at the end of the globbing pattern has the same effect as `dotglob` and `nullglob` in the `bash` shell, and where `:r` removes the filename suffix from the filename (`r` ~ "root", i.e. the root of the name with no suffix) and `:t` removes the directory part of the pathname (`t` ~ "tail", i.e. the tail end of the pathname).

To order the names in descending order (by name), in the `zsh` shell you would use

```bsh
print -rC1 -- ./**/*.sh(DNOn:r:t)
```

... where the added `On` means "order in reverse order by name".

Ordering the output of the `bash` loop(s) at the top is a matter of passing the output through `sort -r`:

```bsh
for name in ./*.sh; do
    basename "$name" .sh
done | sort -r
```

Likewise with the `find` command:

```bsh
find . -name '*.sh' -exec basename {} .sh \; | sort -r
```

Note, though, that this would give you strange results if any filename contains embedded newline characters.

Comment: Thanks, both of ur solutions work, but now I have another thing to do, i need to sort them in descending order, sort -r didnt work

Comment: @MehdiBenabdessalem The question does not mention sorting at all, but I'll add something.